# No. of points on tetrahedron

Tags: permutations, combinations, 3d

[image]

Can you help me in this? I am not getting the way to start the problem.

Comment: It should be clear that any such group of four points from the same face lie only one one face and not multiple faces.  It should also be clear that any selection of four vertices from the same face all lie on the same plane.  So... try counting how many selections of four points lie on the face currently facing us.  Add this to the number of selections of four points from the next face, and add this to the number from the remaining faces to get a total

Comment: I'd tediously count the planes, and then see how many $4$-tuples of points there are on each. I kind of agree the result would be $0$ for some of the planes, but then again I am not very good at seeing stuff, and my internet is often down.

Comment: Yaa how to do this by using concept of combination?

Comment: "*counting how many selections of four points lie on the face currently facing us*"  You could use combinations to count that

Comment: If we were to count just those collections of vertices all from the same face of the tetrahedron, I get a total of $\binom{6}{4}=15$ such combinations per face, and with four faces that accounts for $60$ of the coplanar collections of four points.  That being said, I do also notice other examples of coplanar points.  For example $P_{10},P_5,P_8,P_4$ all lie on the same plane and more examples of that.  Each of these examples are taking the three vertices all from a same edge and the one vertex that doesn't share any face with them for a total of $6$ of this category for a total of $66$

Comment: @Somehow I thought you'd said $64$, not $66$.  Maybe I'm not awake yet.  Sorry.

Comment: I would guess that $4*15=60$ solution is what is intended to be the correct solution. Note that the other solutions of $4$ points are only coplanar if the tetrahedron is a regular tetrahedron (meaning equal side length). The drawing is flat (and not a regular tetrahedron in perspective), so I don't think this is a valid interpretation of the problem.

Comment: @quarague No., it is irrelevant as to whether the tetrahedron was regular.  If you have three colinear points, any fourth point you choose to add will also be coplanar with them.  The three vertices along any of the edges will always be colinear regardless of the regularity of the tetrahedron.  By including the midpoint of the opposite edge, the four points will be coplanar and will not have been counted earlier since these four points do not all lie on a face together.

Comment: @JMoravitz You probably didn't notice that point $P_1$ is always one of the four points.

Comment: @Aretino aah., I certainly did miss that.  Good eye.  In that case, for each of the three faces $P_1$ is a part of, we can select three more vertices... and... those appear to be the only possibilities, giving $3\times \binom{5}{3}=30$.  I blame the blurriness of the picture.

Comment: @JMoravitz We also have $(P_1P_3P_7P_8)$, $(P_1P_4P_5P_9)$ and $(P_1P_2P_6P_{10})$. Total: $33$.

Comment: Can you please type the solution?